# Is it possible to use double-quote characters as part of hashmap key?

Tags: java, key, hashmap

I am going to have a string like "hello " world" as a hashmap key.
The key is actually from user input, that's why it is possible to have something like that as a key.
Is it okay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely. The double-quote character is only "special" as far as Java source code is concerned. You can even escape it within Java itself:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("foo\"bar", "value");
System.out.println(map.get("foo\"bar")); // Will print value
```

Here the key itself is foo"bar - the backslash is just for escaping within the string literal.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course. Even the 0-Character, which often is used as an End-of-String symbol in C is okey in Java, so there are really no constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. If the key is of type `String`, then all characters are allowed. There is no limitation.

Just a reminder: assuming, the user enters:

```
 Jack"o"Lantern
```

then the Java literal is

```
 "Jack\"o\"Lantern"
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others told you, strings in java are allowed to contain all unicode characters, so for keys in a hashmap, you're fine.

But be careful when creating SQL queries, http requests or similar using strings which contain unfiltered user input - your software may be open to SQL injection or cross site scripting attacks then. Using mechanisms like prepared statements instead of string concatenation will help in this case.